# Excel convert DOB to DOB-related expiration date

Tags: excel, date, concatenation, date-formatting

I have various peoples' DOBs. I want to convert them to a format that will serve as their predicted-but-incomplete NY Driver's License expiration date (which is always the person's DOB in some later year). Because (for now) all of the license expiration dates will be sometime before 2030, I would like to essentially chop off the year portion of the DOBs and replace them with "202_" (or if that's not feasible then just "202").

I know how to get Excel to display the DOB without the year, but that isn't helping me so far. My hope had been to use CONCAT to start with that truncated display and then just add "202_" but the date format of the truncated DOB is tripping me up. If I could get Excel to treat the truncated/display DOB as text without Excel converting it to its number version of the whole DOB then that would seem to solve the problem... Or maybe there's another approach I haven't thought of yet?

Comment: Please show what you have and how you want it to look afterward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following formula:

```
=TEXT(A1,"dd.MM.") & "202_"
```

Change date format `"dd.MM"` as you need

[image]